# In a Binary Tree, can two nodes have the same value?

Tags: binary-trees

In a Binary Tree, can two nodes have the same value? For example:

```
     3
    / \
   4   4
  / \
 1   2
```

They are two different nodes, but they have the same value. Here is code:

```
function TreeNode(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = this.right = null;
}
```

```
const r = new TreeNode(3);
r.left = new TreeNode(4);
r.right = new TreeNode(4);
r.left.left = new TreeNode(1);
```

Comment: A binary tree is just a tree where each node has at most two children. I’m assuming you’re referring to a binary *search* tree?

Answer (score 3):

If you say "binary tree", my answer is " yes", since binary tree to me only says: A tree of nodes that only have at most 3 edges, of which two (binary) are pointing in the same direction (to tree leafs).

If you mean a "binary search tree", my answer is "no", since a search tree does not have any advantage in allowing duplicates, since SEARCHING for ONE value in a BST can only result in ONE value, not in two or more. Since BST search is a deterministic algorithm, one of the two mentioned duplicates will never be found and hence is totally useless. Inserting a duplicate in a BST must be skipped since its position in tree is already occupied.

Answer (score 1):

In Binary search trees, the order of nodes are as: 
$leftnode<parentnode<rightnode$.
So, your code will always run into error if both left and right of a parent node is same.

Please go through the following links, for more: 
 http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap13.htm
 https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture8.pdf

Comment: It is important to note that the ordering can be $left\leq parent < right$ or $left < parent \leq right$

Comment: Your first link is about Binary Search Tree. I think that's probably a special kind of binary tree.

PDF files are hard to read and use. I think they're not appropriate for the web. I'm not sure if LeetCode is wrong or your are wrong, but leetcode has a lot of binary tree examples that don't match your `leftnode < parentnode < rightnode` rule.